# Is there any way to ban certain pages from appearing at Firefox Home Page

Tags: firefox, homepage

As you may know, Firefox displays links to frequently visited web pages for some time now. It is customizable to some point, for instant I decided to display so called Top Sites in 4 rows.

My problem is, I cannot seem to get rid of displaying certain links; after I hit "Dismiss" or "Remove From History", they still appear. OK, it might be slightly different link (I want to ban the whole domain), but it still makes me angry.
For example, I have The Old Reader account and I have this opened as a pinned tab. It still lands at Top Sites and I have to click Dismiss over and over again.

Do you know of any extension or about:settings key that would let me block certain domains from appearing in this view?

Or my problem is so niche (like nobody is using FF anymore that I have to hack it myself)?

Comment: One approach would be to use an alternative to the built-in home page.  For example, [GroupSpeedDial](https://fastaddons.com/) is one of the better offerings for Firefox Quantum.  You customize that the way you want and make it your home page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to blacklist an entire domain from being added to the Top Sites page.

However one solution is to prevent Firefox from being able to change the list of top sites. To do this, simply leave no unpinned sites by pinning a site to each available slot on the Top Sites page.